# Stop AngularJS adjusting dates for timezone?

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I'm stuck in an awkward situation where I have to send date/times over the wire without timezone information - to put it simply, the timezone information isn't collected at the time of data-entry and therefore isn't accessible.

This means I have date/times that I just want to echo out exactly as they arrive over the wire, without any accounting for timezone.  I've noticed that AngularJS seems to be automatically assuming the dates are UTC, and is applying a timezone transformation to the data as it arrives, so I'm getting 9am being translated into 8pm AEDT.

Is there a way I can disable this behavour and just have the dates remain exactly as they arrive?

Specifically I'm referring to the $http.get() method. By the time I get access to the returned data it has already been transformed:

```
$http.get('url')
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This will log the transformed dates, so I need to somehow jump in the middle there and stop Angular from transforming the dates.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to just treat the dates as normal strings.

Or you can create proper data objects from the partial data strings by adding your desired timezone and then printing them (or whatever you need to do with them).

Comment: The problem is the $http.get() method has already performed the transformation before I get access to the data. I need to turn that functionality off at the AngularJS level.

Comment: @gnack: I dont think $http.get does anything to the data. If you are saving the Dates into a database as a Datetime object, then requesting a json object from the backend, the json serialiazer does that most likely. So, you can for example change your database model and save the dates as strings, then they will remain unchanged. Problem with this (or any sort of dates saving without timezone) is, that if you have users from different timezones you have no way to tell what time it actually was. So the flaw is in saving dates without timezone info and that is what you should address.

Comment: The database and the product that writes to it is not under my control, so I can't change any of that unfortunately. I know the right way would be to store the timezone and transmit the dates as UTC over the wire, but in this case I'm stuck with the situation described in the question. The serialiser is definitely not changing the dates - they appear correctly in the JSON response, it's definitely getting changed by AngularJS.

Comment: That would never be the case, put scrub shot of your network response and console log, please